# Yet another 'undefined reference to _main'

Tags: c, gcc, ld

I've been attempting to convert the bulk of my current OS project from x86 Assembly over to C and assemble with NASM and compile with MinGW.
When linking, I get these errors:

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol start; defaulting to 00100000
o\main.o:main.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `_main'
```

Here's the script I'm compilng, assembling and linking with:

```
gcc -c main.c -o o\main.o -fno-leading-underscore
nasm boot.asm -o o\boot.o -fcoff
ld -o bin\kernel.bin o\boot.o o\main.o -Tlink.ld
```

...and my linker script is the following:

```
ENTRY(start)
SECTIONS
{
    .text 0x100000 :
    {
        code = .;
        _code = .;
        __code = .;
        *(.text)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }

    .data :
    {
        data = .;
        _data = .;
        __data = .;
        *(.data)
        *(.rodata)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }

    .bss :
    {
        bss = .;
        _bss = .;
        __bss = .;
        *(.bss)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }

    end = .;
    _end = .;
    __end = .;
}
```

When I use nm on main.o, it says that there is something with the symbol '__main', but I've declared it like this:

```
int main()
{
    return 0xDEADBABA;
}
```

Here's boot.asm:

```
MBOOT_PAGE_ALIGN    equ 1<<0    ; Load kernel and modules on a page boundary
MBOOT_MEM_INFO      equ 1<<1    ; Provide your kernel with memory info
MBOOT_HEADER_MAGIC  equ 0x1BADB002 ; Multiboot Magic value
MBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS  equ MBOOT_PAGE_ALIGN | MBOOT_MEM_INFO
MBOOT_CHECKSUM      equ -(MBOOT_HEADER_MAGIC + MBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS)
[bits 32]
[global mboot]
[extern code]
[extern bss]
[extern end]

mboot:
    dd  MBOOT_HEADER_MAGIC
    dd  MBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS
    dd  MBOOT_CHECKSUM
    dd  mboot
    dd  code
    dd  bss
    dd  end
    dd  start

[extern main]
[global start]

start:
    push ebx
    cli
    call main
    jmp $
```

I suspect that this problem I'm having is because of Microsoft being their usual, stupid selves and requiring some sort of underscore prefix or something.
Can anyone please provide a solution to this problem?
Cheers.

Comment: Sure, just edited my question and added it

Comment: Hmm I bet Microsoft has it done just fine :D. What does the 'main' symbol look like if you dont use -fno-leading-underscore?

Comment: It appears as '___main', yep that's 3 underscores

Comment: You aren't using any Microsoft tools here, so, what are you blaming Microsoft for?

Comment: I heard something about the fact that they made certain symbols require the underscore prefix so they didn't clash with others or something along those lines. Other OSes have done it a different way, but Microsoft was too lazy or something. Do you have a solution or is this off-topic?

Comment: Your bashing msft is off-topic. You are using gcc, not Microsoft Visual C++ compiler.

Comment: Yes, but I'm using GCC which as been ported to.. you guessed it, a Microsoft OS. Thus, it has been taylored to account for the quirks of the OS itself.

Comment: I cannot provide a full solution or answer, but there are many problems here, and the underscores/name mangling are the least of them. First, NASM's COFF is not PE-COFF, it's DJGPP-COFF. To my best knowledge, MinGW doesn't use any of the two formats for object file formats. I'm not even sure you can use NASM and MinGW like that. I tried using AS instead of NASM and got some C+asm code compiled, but the .exe image base was way off, not sure how to handle it properly other than by hardcoding. Next, GRUB does not directly support PE images.

Comment: You may be interested in visiting a few sites discussing ways of achieving what you want. [1](http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=15319), [2](http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?t=23013&p=186041), [3](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDevMulti.html), use your favorite web searcher to find more.

Comment: Hmm.. I got my code from http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/2.-Genesis.html so I assume it should all work.. obviously not though..

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is you did not link in the standard C library, which implements `_main` as the main entry point of the program. `_main` calls `main` and does some initialization before and cleanup afterwards. Try using `void _main()` and `exit()` instead of return.

Comment: Maybe he should try `-nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector`

Comment: ^^I've tried that with no success. I'm writing my own OS from scratch here, IIRC, I can't use the standard C lib?